Recommended way to host multiple websites using docker
I read docker docs, and it says that best practices is each container for each app.
So let's say that I want to host around 100 web hosts or more, what would be recommended way?
So should I create for example 100 apache2 containers, 100 mysql containers, 100 SFTP containers (which points to apache2 web root directory), etc..
I don't know if docker is built for this scenario, so I would like to hear recommended way / best practices from experienced people.
Priority is security, be reliable, be scalable and performance.
For security I understand that best scenario is to have each container for each app, so everything is "isolated", but I wonder what about performance, if there will be like 500 containers running for 100 web hosts.
Let's say that HW is something like: 24 CPU, 128GB RAM.

Why do you think Docker is a good fit for this problem?

@vidarlo because of isolated environment --> better security

Docker is not a security layer. Adam Murray's Docker Container Security: Challenges and Best Practices might be a good start to read.

Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they attract low quality, opinionated and spam answers, and the answers become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe the business problem you are working on, the research you have done, and the steps taken so far to solve it.

but I wonder what about performance how will your 100 web sites perform is a question you need to answer with testing. You are "reading Docker documents", are you asking us if it is ok to put all your web sites in one container instead of 100? We can't answer that for you.

Use apache http server virtual hosts.
